# Ошибка архивации приложения в xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, appstore

Пытаюсь загрузить приложение в appstore но при архивации выдает ошибки
Пишет что нет зарегистрированных девайсов хотя мак зарегистрирован в аккаунте разработчика
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас случайно нет неподтвержденных соглашений на developer.apple.com ? Насколько помню, если есть, то сайт может давать отлуп на попытки Xcode загрузить данные и он не может получить список девайсов и профиль

Comment: А как это можно проверить? потому что как мне известно при любой регистрации обязательно ставить галку на все соглашения с правилами итд..

Comment: `Cmd+Shift+4` OSx делает классные скрины, и данные о себе надо было закрасить.

Comment: При регистрации - да, ставишь, но Эппл периодически пересматривает-дополняет соглашения. Зайдите на developer.apple.com -> account ->Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles , там обычно написано.